# I am trying to find the duplicate of elements in an array

Tags: arrays, c

Can someone help me to figure out why my code is unable to accurately find the duplicate of elements?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int array[10];
    int count = 0;

    printf("Enter a maximum of 10 values to store in an array: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        scanf_s("%d", &array[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < 10; j++) {
            if (array[i] == array[j]) {
                count++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("The duplicates are : %d  ", count);
}
```

I'm a beginner at this language so any advice and suggestions to help me solve this exercise will be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Code looks okay for finding the count of dupe elements. Do you need to find the duplicate elements themselves or....? What is the expected output for a given input? If you need to see the elements themselves, you have detected a pair in the innermost block with `array[i]` and `array[j]` so you can simply print it then. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: as previous poster said, code looks ok, you will not create duplicates because in 2nd loop you starts from i+1, so thats right.

Comment: As a tip i would use a constant value with the number of elements with #define NUM_ELEMENTS 10 and use then NUM_ELEMENTS instead of 10 in loops and array definition.

Comment: I just see a problem if the array is 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8 you will find more duplicates than really exists, in theory you would need to create a secondary array with the numbers that you have found and remove them from search.

Comment: in the case tthat i told you your algorithm will say that you have 45 duplicates if i'm not wrong and with 10 numbers you can have 45 duplicates :)

Comment: and when it as for duplicates it tells you the number of duplicates or the number of times that you find duplicates?, it is not the same thing

Comment: Suppose you have numbers like 4,4,1,2.. Now your expected output should be count 2 (since two 4)..but as per your logic count will come 1..since in inner loop you are not iterating whole array . To get the expected result you should iterate the whole  array in inner loop also(I.e j from 0 to < 10) & compare like, if ( i! =j && array[I]==array[j]) {count++;break;}

Comment: oh i didnt see the break line inside the 2nd loop, that changes it. It would work for 8,8,8,8,... example that i told you previously

Comment: @goblinda but really there is 1 duplicate in your example, so the code is ok then

Comment: with the break line inside 2nd loop it would work fine for all situations, for example in 4,4,5,3,4,6 it would find 2 duplicates and thats right (2 times the number 4).

Comment: @sulekha can you show an example where it goes wrong? i have been analyzing the code and i see it ok

Comment: @hamboy75 Hi, so um for example, when i entered the values: 1, 10, 20, 1, 25, 1, 10, 30 , 25, 1. i thought it would give me a duplicate value of 3 ( 1, 10, 25) but i get the duplicate value of 5 instead.

Comment: @Suleka: there are 5 duplicates in your example: `1`, `10`, `1` again, `25` and one more `1`. Removing duplicates from the array would remove 5 entries.

Comment: @chqrlie he wanted a program that finds how many numbers have at least one duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the first loop runs 10 times even if the user enters less numbers. You can fix that by doing:

```
for (int i = 0; scanf_s("%d", &array[i]) == 1 && i < 10; i++);
```

Then the logic of the other two loops is wrong. I initially got wrong what you meant. I thought you wanted to know how many times a number is duplicated. So I wrote the wrong program and then modified it for your purposes. Here is your program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int n[10];
    int dupes[5], d = 0;
    int flag = 1, omg;

    for ( omg = 0; scanf("%d", &n[omg]) == 1 && omg < 10; omg++);

    for (int i = 0; i < omg; i++) {
    
        for (int j = i+1; j < 10; j++) {
        
            if( n[i] == n[j] ) {
            
                if( d > 0 ) {
                
                    for(int k = 0; k < d; k++) {
                
                        if( n[i] == dupes[k] ) {
                    
                            flag = 0;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            
                if( flag ) {
                    dupes[d] = n[i];
                    ++d;
                    break;
                }
                else {
            
                    flag = 1;
                    break;
                }
            } // end outer if
        }
    }

    printf("There are %d numbers that have at least one dupe\n", d);

    return 0;
}
```

I named a variable `omg` out of desperation, writing this program was a nightmare. (Because it came from the ashes of a previous program)

Comment: are you using my comment to create an answer? :) and the first half of your comment focus also in a small detail , not important for the main question.

Comment: While I was writing my answer, your comment wasn't even there.

Comment: 13 minutes before :)

Comment: Man I am writing from a phone, English is not my language and I also tried to write a working code while answering. Then I surrendered about the code because I've understood would take time. I am working on it, I am going to post it.

Comment: @Davide Thanks for the suggestion but what is the == 1 part for? what does it do?

Comment: @suleka it means that scanf successful read and stored exactly one input.

Comment: @chqrlie yes my analysis was wrong, I just got it all wrong

Comment: Posting on SO from a phone is a nightmare :)

Comment: Definitely! But I'm getting used to it

Answer (score 0):

I use a structure 'Number' which contains the number and its duplicate, then I fill the array and I put it in ascending order then I calculate the number of duplicate of each number and I fill in the strecture like this :

my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define size 10

typedef struct Number
{
     int number;
     int duplicate;
}Number;



int main()
{
    int array[size];
    Number array2[size];
    int count = 0;
    printf("Enter a maximum of 10 values to store in an array: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }
    int temp=size;
    int temppppp=0;
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
         for(int j=i+1;j<size;j++)
         {
              if(array[i]>array[j])
              {
                   temppppp=array[i];
                   array[i]=array[j];
                   array[j]=temppppp;
              }
         }
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
          printf("[%d]",array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    while(i<size)
    {count=1;
         while(i<(size-1)&&array[i]==array[i+1])
         {
               count++;
               i++;
         }
         if(count>=2)
         {
              array2[j].number=array[i-1];
              array2[j].duplicate=count;
              j++;
         }
           i++;
    }
    int p=0;
    while(p<j)
    {
         printf("\n[%d] has duplicated %d times !\n",array2[p].number,array2[p].duplicate);
         p=p+1;
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    printf("\nThere are %d duplicate values\n", j);
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code correctly determines the number of duplicate entries in the array.

If instead you want to determine the number of duplicated values, you must modify the algorithm:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int array[10] = { 0 };
    int count = 0;

    printf("Enter a maximum of 10 values to store in an array: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        scanf_s("%d", &array[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            if (array[i] == array[j]) {
                if (i < j)
                    count++;
                if (i != j)
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("There are %d duplicate values\n", count);
    return 0;
}
```